# Need help identifying/translating a plaque in Tangier, Morocco

Tags: history, tangier, arabic-language

My wife and I were in Tangier a little over a month ago and I had taken a picture of a plaque near the Kasbah Museum. It must have been important or interesting but, silly me, I neglected to make a note of why.

Does anyone know what this plaque is for or what it says?

[image: Plaque near Kasbah Museum]

Comment: The big words in the middle are "??? the Kasbah". I thought the ??? might be "museum" but that would be مَتْحَف...

Comment: جَوَامِع‎ has a few meanings, but one is a certain kind of mosque. So I think it is "The Kasbah Mosque".

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is written in Classic Arabic (MSA), using the Maghrebi script, the translation is:

> بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم

In the name of Allah, most merciful and gracious.

> فِي بُيُوتٍ أَذِنَ اللَّهُ أَن تُرْفَعَ وَيُذْكَرَ فِيهَا اسْمُهُ يُسَبِّحُ لَهُ فِيهَا بِالْغُدُوِّ وَالْآصَالِ

Quran 24:36: In houses, which Allah hath permitted to be raised to honour; for the celebration, in them, of His name: In them is He glorified in the mornings and in the evenings, (again and again)

> رِجَالٌ لَّا تُلْهِيهِمْ تِجَارَةٌ وَلَا بَيْعٌ عَن ذِكْرِ اللَّهِ وَإِقَامِ الصَّلَاةِ وَإِيتَاءِ الزَّكَاةِ ۙ يَخَافُونَ يَوْمًا تَتَقَلَّبُ فِيهِ الْقُلُوبُ وَالْأَبْصَارُ

Quran 24:37: By men whom neither traffic nor merchandise can divert from the Remembrance of Allah, nor from regular Prayer, nor from the practice of regular Charity: Their (only) fear is for the Day when hearts and eyes will be transformed (in a world wholly new).

> بني عقب تحرير مدينة طنجة من يد الانجليز سنة 1095هـ الموافق 1674م
>   بأمر من السلطان المولى اسماعيل

Built after the liberation of Tangier from the English in 1095 Hijri - 1674 CE by orders from Sultan Almawla Ismael.

> رمم من طرف وزارة الأوقاف والشؤون الإسلامية وأعيد فتحه يوم الجمعة 17 شعبان 1436هـ
>   هـ الموافق 05 يونيو 2015م

Renovated by the Ministry of Islamic Affairs and reopened on Friday, Shaa'ban 17th, 1436 Hijri. 05 June 2015 CE.

**The big word in the middle:**

> **جامع القصبة**

**Alqasabah Mosque.**

Moroccans (Algerians and Tunisians as well), use different names of months, North Arabs use other system and eastern Arabs (such as GCC countries and Egypt) use the English translated names of months, in this plaque they used the latter. Perhaps because it's the most commonly understood one.

Comment: Thank you *so* much for the detailed answer, Nean!

Comment: You are a legend sir!

Comment: This is perfect +1, I would add that in Morocco, it is common to teach both colloquial and (in this case) Modern Standard Arabic as NDT noted, including at language institutes.

Comment: @Mikey This is true for all Arab countries, including my own. We use a dialect for daily use, and we MSA for school, writing, news, magazines, etc. However, due to satellite TVs and internet, Arabic dialects are starting to have common words and it's quite easier for two Arabs to communicate using their local different dialects without falling back to MSA that often..

Comment: I stalked some of your great answers Nean :D, where are you from ? something GCC, KSA , right ?

Comment: @Accountantم yes, GCC

Comment: @NeanDerThal OK, thanks for satisfying my curiosity :D, [أحسن ناس يا باشا](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en&tab=wT#view=home&op=translate&sl=ar&tl=en&text=%D8%A3%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86%20%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B3%20%D9%8A%D8%A7%20%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%A7) 

Comment: @Accountantم تسلم ياباشا

Comment: What is meant by "(Lit is such a Light)"?

Comment: @AzorAhai the verse translation was quoted from a quran translation website, it sounded weird to me, i checked another site and I even sounded more weird. I thought it would mean something for natives..

Comment: @NeanDerThal Is it part of the translation, or a comment on the translation?

Comment: @AzorAhai I have posted this on [islam.stackexchange](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/53534/what-does-lit-is-such-a-light-mean-in-the-translation-of-quran-2436) they may give better answer. Also these are some [other translations](https://quran.com/24/36?translations=21,20,19,101,84,85,22,18,95,17) for the same verse. And no it's not part of the direct translation of the Arabic script.

Comment: @NeanDerThal As to your previous comment on if it means something to natives, it doesn't at all.

Comment: My guess it has something to do with the previous verse, or the name of the chapter " Al nour" which means "the light". I am gonna remove it, it seems out of context here.

Comment: @AzorAhai ummm, I guess it is part of the *explanation* not the translation. because the verse started with "..... in houses" . So the interpreter tries to explain and answer the question, "what is it in the houses" ?

Comment: @Accountantم Your guess is as good as mine; but I guess we agree it's extremely confusing.

Comment: There is a [little typخ](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/53534/what-does-lit-is-such-a-light-mean-in-the-translation-of-quran-2436#comment90749_53534) "رمم من طرف".